# Hashmap with Tuple for key and mapped value

Tags: java

What i would like is to create a Hashtable that takes a pair of integers as a key and maps it to a pair of (Integer,String).So having 2 specific integers i would like to be able to acquire both the Integer and the String they map to.What i have done so far:

```
class Tuple {
      public Tuple (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
      }
      public int k;
      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 5 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 5 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }
      @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) { 
            if (o == this) { 
                return true; 
            }   
            if (!(o instanceof Tuple)) { 
                return false; 
            } 
            Tuple c = (Tuple) o; 
            return Double.compare(x, c.x) == 0
                    && Double.compare(y, c.y) == 0; 
        } 
      private int x;
      private int y;
    }
```

I created a Tuple class for the key and i initialized the Hashtable like this:

```
HashMap<Tuple, String> seen = new HashMap<Tuple,String>();
```

where as a String i put `String1:"Integer+"#"+String"`.
So for a specific key (i,j) i can retrieve this String and separate it to Integer and String.For many and very large integers though String1 takes up a lot of memory since i think for every additional character this string need 2 more bytes.So if i want to store 100000 it would need 12 bytes instead of 4(int's bytes).I tried creating a similar class with Tuple with y being String but i can't retrieve both values only by having (i,j) key.Any ideas?

Comment: 1) I would suggest to replace Double.compare with Integer.compare.
2) I don't understand why you cannot create a similar class with Tuple for the value (with y as String).

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis would this be more memory efficient than the <Tuple,String> option?

Comment: Yes, you could call your class `IntIntTuple` and create a similar class like `IntStringTuple`. (There are many options for the details, but this is the basic idea). So what do you mean by *i can't retrieve both values only by having (i,j) key*? You'd then just do `IntStringTuple is = seen.get(intIntTuple);` and do with the `IntStringTuple` whatever you want...